# User defined function erroring out when refresh is performed on another workbook

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions, volatile, vba

I have a perfectly working User Defined function (Volatile) in one workbook (WB 1). However when I switch to another workbook (WB 2) and do a refresh (F9) and switch back to WB 1 the UDF errors (#VALUE) out. However when I refresh (F9) on WB 1 again, the function starts working.

This is a problem because I am referencing the values from WB 1 in WB 2.

Comment: Is it possible to post the UDF and what do you mean by volatile?

Comment: "I have a perfectly working User Defined function" - seems like you *don't*, but no way to tell what the issue is unless you post it...

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the UDF code references the `ActiveWorkbook` somewhere so when you switch to "WB 2", then *that* is your active workbook and not "WB 1", in which case things that, for example, reference particular cells may not work as expected. As you said, when you go back to "WB 1" and recalculate, things start working again, which further proves this.

Note that clicking <kbd>F9</kbd> will recalculate **all** open workbooks *in the **same session** of Excel*, not just the active workbook. If you want to just recalculate (or refresh, as you call it) the active worksheet, you can do <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> instead.